# Every field value not showing in eloquent relationship Laravel 5.4.

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have two models. employee and pasport model.Both are in one to one relationship. Employee and pasport model has one tone one relation. I am giving the code of my models and the command for tinker below.

```
public function pasport()
        {
           return $this->hasOne(pasport::class);
        }

public function employee()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo(employee::class);
   }    


    App\employee::find("59f057decd58ff0c6e99f1f7")->pasport

    App\pasport {#715
    _id: MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId {#705
    +"oid": "59f05d04cd58ff0c6e99f1f9",
    },
    employee_id: "59f057decd58ff0c6e99f1f7",
    employee_passport: "123456",
    }
```

employee_name is missing.How can I specify the column name that I want?